# How to fixed window size in eclipse rcp e4

Tags: eclipse-rcp, e4

I didn't want it to be dragged to change the size. I'm the primary learner.
I create a part in the Application.e4xmi.

The structure is 'Window and dialogs ---> Trimmed Window ----> Controls ----> Part', then I created a class to associate it.

Answer (score 3):

If you just have one part in the trimmed window you can set the style of the window to prevent resizing.

You do this by setting a `styleOverride` value in the 'persisted state' section on the 'Supplementary' tab of the 'Trimmed Window' page in the Application.e4xmi.

Add a persisted state value with a key of 'styleOverride' and a value of '96' which corresponds to the 'SWT.CLOSE | SWT.TITLE' style.

[image]